# Delete data older than 13 months not dropping partial months data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to keep a rolling 13 months data, delete data older than 13 months, keeping complete months of data. Should not drop partial months data while maintaining rolling 13 months. So if my delete date is anything other than 1, I would preserve the whole months data. Need help writing a SQL query for this

Comment: You need to provide example code representing your data, and your coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` statement would look something like this in MySQL (as the question was originally tagged):

```
delete from t
    where datecol < date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval (1 - day(curdate())) day), interval -13 month);
```

In SQL Server, it would look like:

```
delete from t
    where datecol < dateadd(month, -13,
                            dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()),
                                    cast(getdate() as date)
                                   )
                           )
```

Of course, copy your data before testing this.

Two notes of caution:

1. I am very reluctant to delete data.  What is the harm of leaving old data in the table.
2. If you do need to remove data one month at a time, then you should look into partitioning and drop the partition instead.  Dropping partitions is much more efficient.